# How to retain only one record but extract data from several two rows for a unique reference number

Tags: r, duplicates

I am trying to remove duplicates but need to retain the first data from 1 row and another data from another row/s in [R] programming.

For example, I have data like this:

| ID | Transaction # | Process # | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | ID1_T1 | P1 | 2022-01-03 | 2022-01-05 |
| ID1 | ID1_T1 | P2 | 2022-01-06 | 2022-01-10 |
| ID1 | ID1_T1 | P3 | 2022-01-11 | 2022-01-20 |
| ID1 | ID1_T1 | P4 | 2022-01-21 | 2022-01-31 |
| ID2 | ID2_T1 | P1 | 2022-01-06 | 2022-01-11 |
| ID2 | ID2_T1 | P2 | 2022-01-12 | 2022-01-18 |
| ID2 | ID2_T1 | P3 | 2022-01-19 | 2022-01-25 |
| ID3 | ID3_T1 | P1 | 2022-01-21 | 2022-01-22 |

And I need to simplify it into this:

| ID | Transaction # | Process # | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | ID1_T1 | P1 | 2022-01-03 | 2022-01-31 |
| ID2 | ID2_T1 | P1 | 2022-01-06 | 2022-01-25 |
| ID3 | ID3_T1 | P1 | 2022-01-11 | 2022-01-22 |

Retaining only the first Start Date and last End Date of the transaction per unique ID and Transaction #.

I'm expecting help on how to code this in R using the tidyverse library since I'm not yet familiar with Data.table.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `group_by` + `summarise`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID, Transaction) %>%
  summarise(Process = first(Process),
            Start_Date = first(Start_Date), # or min(Start_Date)
            End_Date = last(End_Date),      # or max(End_Date)
            .groups = "drop")
```

Comment: Hi Darren Tsai,

Ty for your code.

However, I need to correct my question. 
What if, in the original dataframe, row 3 (P3) and row 4 (P4) was interchanged. And what I really need to get is the latest End_Date which is in P4?

can I use min and max instead like this:

sample %>%
  group_by(ID, TRANSACTION) %>%
  summarise(PROCESS = first(PROCESS),
            START_DATE = min(START_DATE),
            END_DATE = max(END_DATE),
            .groups = "drop"
            )